# mypy incompatible types list<nothing> has the type list<str>

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, type-annotation, prompt-toolkit

I am using prompt-toolkit python library with the code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import checkboxlist_dialog

results: list[str] = checkboxlist_dialog(
    title="CheckboxList dialog",
    text="What would you like in your breakfast ?",
    values=[
        ("eggs", "Eggs"),
        ("bacon", "Bacon"),
        ("croissants", "20 Croissants"),
        ("daily", "The breakfast of the day"),
    ],
).run()
```

When I run mypy 0.931 I get:

```
test.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type "List[str]")
test.py:4: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
test.py:4: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
test.py:7: error: Argument "values" to "checkboxlist_dialog" has incompatible type "List[Tuple[str, str]]"; expected "Optional[List[Tuple[<nothing>, Union[str, MagicFormattedText, List[Union[Tuple[str, str], Tuple[str, str, Callable[[MouseEvent], None]]]], Callable[[], Any], None]]]]"
```

I am not sure if the problem is with my code, since the return value is something like `['eggs', 'bacon']` which is a `list[str]`. Also this error from mypy is strange, since I don't think I should use covariant here. Any hints on what may be the problem?

Comment: Are you asking about the first or the second error message?

Comment: Actually the first, but both are related. If you add `# type: ignore` to values. It shows no message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that mypy has very little information about the `checkboxlist_dialog` function, and certainly doesn't know that its return type can be figured out from the `value` argument.

You may instead have to write:

```
from typing import cast

results = cast(list[string], checkboxlist_dialog(....))
```

which tells mypy that you know what you're doing, and the return type really is a `list[string]`, no matter what it thinks.

Comment: mypy that has no information doesn't complain about wrong types. I already checked that  https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/dialogs.py#L210 and types seem to be fine, so to actually understand that better there is need of stronger mypy knowledge.

Comment: I agree with you.  If mypy is actually reading that file (rather than a library stub), then it ought to be able to figure out that _T is a string.  But it's not.  You have to decide if it's worth your while trying to debug mypy or getting on with the rest of your program.  Sometimes mypy is quite helpful.  Sometimes you have to deal with the fact that it's still a work in progress and isn't perfect.

Comment: @FrankYellin do you think it is a bug from mypy 0.931 then? With your solution and stopping ignoring types I still get the second error, this is very annoying since it is the example on prompt-toolkit documentation.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that second error message.  `mypy` really doesn't want to bind `_T`, does it.  As a last bit of desperation, maybe try pulling the `values` argument and putting it into a variable.  Maybe even tell mypy that the variable is type `list[tuple[str, str]]`.    Again,  it's up to you how much time you want to spend fighting mypy when it's clearly (I think) wrong.